# Move Character from point A to B smoothly unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So, Hey guys I am new to unity. I have a small doubt. I have a player who is a child of the topcube in a 3 stackcube placed upon eachother.
These cubes have a target position to move once the user clicks on them.
Like imagine there are 3 points in my world. POINT A with location coordinates as(0,0,1),POINT B with (0,0,2),POINT C with (0,0,3) and the 3 stack cube is place on (0,0,0) with the player attached as a child to topcube in that 3stackcube.
All these points(A,B,C) has a script called targetpoint with a variable bool isFilled(default as false) in them which becomes true when one of the cube reaches to its target position.
Further im checking whenever the cubes reaches their target position make isFilled true and check to see if there is a child attached if yes get the animator of the child and trigger jump animation. The jump animation is an inplace animation.
So I want to programmatically move my character +1 towards the direction he is facing (if he is facing z move + 1 in z, if x move +1 in x like this)when the cube he is attached reached its target position while also playing jump animation.
I did a code. it doesnt seem to be working. And sorry for huge paragraphs. Im totally new to coding and asking doubts. Any help will be helpful thanks.

```
 [SerializeField] public List<targetpoint> waypoints;
    [SerializeField] float moveSpeed = 2f;
    [SerializeField] AudioClip[] surferSounds;
    [SerializeField] GameObject particleToPlay;
    int waypointIndex = 0;
    float t;

    //Cached Reference
    AudioSource audioSource;

    //State
    public bool move = false;

    void Start()
    {
        transform.position = this.transform.position;
        t = 0f;

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (move == true)
        {
            MoveTarget();
        }
    }

    void MoveTarget()
    {

        //Time.timeScale = 0.1f;
        if (waypointIndex <= waypoints.Count - 1)
        {
            var targetPosition = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
            transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            if (transform.position == targetPosition)
            {

                //Debug.Log(t);
                if (waypoints[waypointIndex].isFilled == false)
                {
                    waypoints[waypointIndex].isFilled = true;
                    AudioClip clip = surferSounds[UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, surferSounds.Length)];
                    var storeToDestroy = Instantiate(particleToPlay, targetPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    Destroy(storeToDestroy , 5f);
                    audioSource.PlayOneShot(clip);
                    move = false;
                }
                else if(waypoints[waypointIndex].isFilled == true)
                {
                    waypointIndex++;
                    targetPosition = waypoints[waypointIndex].transform.position;
                    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, targetPosition, moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
                if (this.gameObject.transform.childCount > 0)
                {
                    var storeChild = gameObject.transform.GetChild(1).gameObject;
                    StartCoroutine(GravityAndJump(storeChild,storeChild.transform.position+1*transform.forward,1f));
                }
                else
                {
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    IEnumerator GravityAndJump(GameObject child, Vector3 newPosition , float time)
    {

        var elapsedTime = 0f;
        var startingPosition = child.transform.position;
        while(elapsedTime < time)
        {
            child.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("shouldJump?");
            child.transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startingPosition, newPosition, (elapsedTime / time));
            elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }


        //storeChild.GetComponent<Animator>().SetFloat("JumpSpeed", 1f);
        //yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
        //gameObject.GetComponentInChildren<Rigidbody>().useGravity = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain more clearly how it isn't working please? i.e. is your character not moving at all or are they moving the wrong amount?

Comment: My character is moving but in a wrong amount @Giles Roberts. I think it has the to do something with my lerp condition. not able to figure out exactly what\

Comment: To understand a bit more, are you expecting your character to jump from way point to way point or move smoothly between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I want to programmatically move my character +1 towards the direction he is facing (if he is facing z move + 1 in z, if x move +1 in x like this)

You can get the forward direction for a GameObject using with [transform.forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) you can use this to calculate target position in front of the GameObject.

Set target position some distance in front of the transform

```cs
targetPosition = transform.position + (transform.forward * distance);
```

Move towards target position at some speed.

```cs
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition, Time.deltaTime * followSpeed);
```

**Determining arrival to targetPosition**

When it comes to determining if transform has arrive to target destination you should measure the distance instead of comparing that the vectors are the same.

So replace this:

```cs
if (transform.position == targetPosition){}
```

With something like this:

```cs
if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, targetPosition) < .001f){
  transform.position = targetPosition;
}
```

Unless you strictly set two vectors to same values it's likely that they will never be considered equal due to how floating point numbers work.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I dont have a problem with my cube's going and settling on their place. instead i want my character to move from point a to b by 1

Comment: as you see in my code. i tried taking my character initial position and added  +1 * transform.forward to move on the direction he is facing but my problem is he isn't moving exactly one in unit but a lot of units before the while becomes false. So is there another method to achieve this. My only problem is to move my character +1 the side he is facing with playing the jump animation smoothly instead of him to glitch forward to the position and then play the jump anim. The jump animation im using here is a inplace animation so i should move my character programmatically to make it look good.

Comment: Don't know how your animator controller is setup, but setting animator trigger each loop could cause issues with some setups as could animations that modify x,z positions in this case. You could also implement the jump programmatically by combining lerp with y-position from or based on [animation curve](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCurve-ctor.html).